# Lua - ‘String to Hex’ and ‘Hex to String’ formulas

Tags: lua, hex

I’ve tried to keep various examples of Lua code I’ve come across to re-use, with strtohex() and hextostr() being one an example, but I can only find strToHex() - below..

```
local s = "175"
local function strToHex(s)
  local bytes = {}
  for i=1,s:len()  do
    bytes[#bytes+1] = ('%2x'):format(s:byte(i,i))
  end
  return table.concat(bytes, ' ')
  --return table.concat(bytes, '')
end
print(strToHex(s))
```

Does anyone have a example of hextostr() they could share ?

Answer (score 4):

```lua
local function hexdecode(hex)
   return (hex:gsub("%x%x", function(digits) return string.char(tonumber(digits, 16)) end))
end

local function hexencode(str)
   return (str:gsub(".", function(char) return string.format("%02x", char:byte()) end))
end

print(hexdecode(hexencode("Hello, World!")))
```

Comment: Change '%2x' format to '%02x' in hexencode() to avoid missing first zero for 0x00 to 0x0f range. I couldn't edit it because edit should be at least 6 characters instead of one :)